# Cannot find the Test Project in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I could not find the Test Project in the VS2008.

Can anyone point me out what components I need to install?

PS: I cannot afford the Resharper.

Comment: Added the visualstudio2008 tag.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2008 do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Test projects come with the Team and Professional Editions.

I'm going to assmue you have Pro.  Information on how to create and run unit tests can be found at [msdn: Using Testing Tools in VIsual Studio Professional Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902.aspx).

If you don't have Pro or better, then you can grab the [nUnit testing framework](http://www.nunit.org/index.php).  It's free and is what MS modeled their framework on.

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of Visual Studio 2008 are you using? Test Projects are supported in Professional and above, but not Express - I don't *think* they're in Standard either.

(Note that Test Projects were only in the Team edition of VS2005, but they got moved to Pro for VS2008.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Team System or Professional edition. Can't afford ReSharper??? Man that's what I call tight budget. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you switch **Unit Test Tools** options, when you install your VS2008 >= **PROFESIONAL**, to **on** ?

[image: VS 2008 Instalator]